# How to convert NSdata to nsurl in ios

Tags: ios, nsdata

I'm trying play video in tableView using the URL I'm fetching the URL from the database using the json now I'm using the `NSMutabledata` to get the string form the database and I m appending on the NSData .

When I'm passing the data I'm converting into string and I'm passing the URL to the movieplayer
the problem is I'm getting the null error in my console can any one suggest me how to convert the NSData to URL I'm stuck here for long time need help

this the code I have used to get the string from json and pass it to url

```
-(void)setDataSource:(vedios *)inVideosObj
{
    self.titile.text = inVideosObj.title;

    url =[NSURL URLWithString:inVideosObj.video];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
     [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
```

this is the code which I'm trying to convert the nsdata to string and passing to the movieplayer.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // NSAssert(self.responseData, @"Response data should not be nil");

    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.responseData bytes] ];

    NSAssert(self.responseData, @"This should not be nil for a valid response");

    NSLog(@"data :%@",urlString);
    MPMoviePlayerController *mov = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    //  MPMoviePlayerController *mov = [[MPMoviePlayerController   alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"length %d",[self.responseData length]);

    // MPMoviePlayerController *mov = [[MPMoviePlayerController   alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    self.movieplayer = mov;
    [self.movieplayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,20, 100, 100)];

    // self.movieplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.movieplayer.view];
    [self.movieplayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.movieplayer play];
}
```

Comment: is `NSLog(@"data :%@",urlString);` shows a valid url.?

Comment: no its showing data nill error in console

Comment: try with other [encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringEncoding)

Comment: i have ready tried but its show the same data nill